# How to get current batch prediction inside keras training cycle?

Tags: keras

I am using `_loss, _acc = model.train_on_batch(x, y)` training approach. Now I want to get current batch model predictions(outputs) to find incorrect predictions and save same to use later in hard negative mining. How to get current outputs?

Comment: I don't think keras exposes that, you will have to `predictions = model.predict_on_batch(x)`. That's terrible for performance, I know. But the other way would be implementing a custom training, sort of like following a tutorial like this: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/eager/custom_training_walkthrough

Comment: In tensorflow it is easy to do, I did similar thing. There is model.outputs property in keras and loss is calculated internaly using this outputs, but can't find a way to use it.. K.eval not working.

Comment: That tutorial should use eager execution, thus no eval is needed. You cannot eval an output without feeding the input (in practice it's would be the same as calling `predict_on_batch`)